# Can Repeated Use of Rsync Cause a System Slowdown?

Tags: rsync

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04 on an ancient Dell Dimension 4550 desktop that I use to backup 13 security cameras.  The backup is performed 4 times daily via cron and rsync.  Oftentimes, by the time the cronscript has reached the 13th camera, the copying has slowed down to a painful crawl, sometimes taking 1 to 2 minutes to copy each 650KB image file.  For the sake of speeding things up, I have added the -W and --ignore-existing switches to the rsync cronscript since these are not extremely important to me, but the speed increase has only been marginal.  I've even added a "killall rsync" script that executes 2 & 1/2 hours after each cronscript because there are times that the previous cronscript is still running rsync when the next schedule time arrives (3 hours).  Here's the backup cronscript if it helps:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOGFILE=/data/cameras/"$(date "+%Y-%m")_Archive.log"
PWORD=************
echo "-----  Starting Camera Archive @ $(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T")  -----" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.201
CAMNAME=FrontRight
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing  $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.202
CAMNAME=FrontLeft
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.203
CAMNAME=Driveway
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.204
CAMNAME=Garage
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.205
CAMNAME=SideYard
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.206
CAMNAME=Basement
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.207
CAMNAME=Sunroom
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.208
CAMNAME=BackLeft
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.209
CAMNAME=BackRight
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.210
CAMNAME=Utilities
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.211
CAMNAME=Bedroom
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.212
CAMNAME=Extra
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
CAMIP=root@192.168.1.213
CAMNAME=Motorhome
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Starting "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
sshpass -p $PWORD rsync -rW --ignore-existing $CAMIP:/data/output/$CAMNAME /data/cameras
rm -rf /data/cameras/$CAMNAME/.keep
echo "$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T") : Ending "$CAMNAME" script" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
echo "======  Ending Camera Archive @ $(date "+%m-%d-%Y %T")  ======" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
echo " " >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#####
```

Comment: How many files end up in /data/cameras? Does writing each of the cameras to a different output directory speed things up?

Comment: The number of image files range from 0 to somewhere around 2-4k per day, per camera.  The directories are /data/output/[date] on the cameras, which each have their own Raspberry Pi and run from a 32GB card.  The rsynced files are stored on the server by /data/cameras/[camera name]/[date], so the number of files in the upper /data/cameras directory on the server easily reach a million.  The upper /data/output/[date] directory on the individual cameras which is rsynced from will only span 2-days, and never more than a 24-hour period.

Comment: The second question was meant to have you test writing to different directories. For example, create subdirectories in /data/camera for each of the cameras and have rsync copy into those directories instead of /data/cameras. Then, you'll probably notice that all cameras take the same amount of time instead of the last being much slower than the first. If thats the case, it points to the problem of many files in one directory and you can figure out how to mitigate this (e.g. noatime, combining into one dir after completion, or other tricks)

Comment: It is quite possible that I'm not understanding you, but the destination directories are split up by camera name and then date... "/data/cameras/[camera name]/[date]".  Looking at the processes using Glances, I'm not seeing anything hogging the memory or processes, just very slow rsync copying.  I am getting another idea... it just so happens that the later cameras are wifi connected through an extender.  The extender is not absolutely necessary, but I use it for the other side of the house and back yard.  I'm thinking about temporarily taking the extender out and seeing what happens.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding on my part as I thought they were all ending up in same directory. Could also try reversing the order in the script and seeing if you still get the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks much!  I may have to see what happens by reversing the order as you suggest.  I disconnected my extender, and when the 1800 hour cronjob arrived, it was (and still is) just as slow.

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help.  I just can't get that last camera to speed up, even when placed at the beginning of the script.  I think I'll change the Micro SD card since that could be a source of the problem.  Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: This matter can be considered closed.  After changing the Micro SD & not seeing a difference, I took drastic measures. I turned my wifi extender off mid xfer of the slowest & farthest camera.  When the extender went offline, that xfer paused a couple minutes while it made the new handshake with the wifi router.  Once the handshake was made, the xfer took off at lightning speed.  So my guess is that when I put the slowest camera at the top of the script, I could not see the slower speed due to the low number of files to be xferred.  I'm now going to change the wifi extender to a wired AP.